# How to get the size and location of a cell in dataGrid in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, wpfdatagrid

I've started to work with a dataGrid in WPF, but coming from WinForm, its a little different from what I'm used to..

My problem right now is that i need to get a specific cell's rectangle (so I can access its size & location).

In WinForm's datagrid there where a method called:

```
cellRectangle = dataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(columnIndex, rowIndex, cutOverflow)
```

However, I cant seem to find anything like this in WPF, and everything i can find online is massivly complicated compared to what i used to be able to do in WinForm..

If possible, I would like to avoid any XAML code, and write it all in C# code

Hope someone of you have a solution to my problem.

Comment: That's an unusual goal for WPF. Why do you need the size and location of a cell, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I need to be able to place controls (comboBoxes, buttons, etc.) on top of the cell, so that it looks like the control is within the cell itself, and i WinForm I could just make the control's size and location equal to the cells size and location.

Comment: @Anthony In WPF you can likely change the template of a cell so you can make your contols in the template and it would place it in the cell correctly.

Comment: @Anthony, I think in WPF controls take the whole cell size by default. Buy in any case, you can use [styles and templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/styling-and-templating) to do this in WPF, for example via [CellTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplate?view=netframework-4.7.2). Finding and changing the cells manually is not the WPF way.

Answer (score 0):

WPF does not work with coordinates, but containers. If you want to put something into a DataGridCell, find it and put the new content in DataGridCell.Content.

In my sample, you can enter row and column number, then press Execute Code Button. This will place a button into the grid at the desired location. After clicking on Click Me, the button disappears and the old cell content is shown.

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridCell.MainWindow"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
          xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
          xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridCell"
          mc:Ignorable="d"
          Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="LightGray">
      <Label Content="Row:"/>
      <TextBox Name="RowTextBox" Text="2"/>
      <Label Content="Column:"/>
      <TextBox Name="ColumnTextBox" Text="1"/>
      <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Execute Code" Name="ExecuteButton"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataGrid Name="MainDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col0" Binding="{Binding Col0}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1" Binding="{Binding Col1}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col2" Binding="{Binding Col2}" />
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>


using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace DataGridCell {

  public class RowData {
    public string Col0 { get; set; }
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public string Col2 { get; set; }
  }

  public partial class MainWindow: Window {
    public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();
      var dataList = new List<RowData>();
      dataList.Add(new RowData {Col0="0.0", Col1="0.1", Col2="0.2"});
      dataList.Add(new RowData {Col0="1.0", Col1="1.1", Col2="1.2"});
      dataList.Add(new RowData {Col0="2.0", Col1="2.1", Col2="2.2"});
      dataList.Add(new RowData {Col0="3.0", Col1="3.1", Col2="3.2"});
      ObservableCollection<RowData> custdata = new ObservableCollection<RowData>(dataList);
      MainDataGrid.DataContext = custdata;
      ExecuteButton.Click+=ExecuteButton_Click;
    }

    ContentControl cell;
    object oldContent;

    private void ExecuteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      var row = int.Parse(RowTextBox.Text);
      var col = int.Parse(ColumnTextBox.Text);
      var cellContent = (FrameworkElement)MainDataGrid.Columns[col].GetCellContent(MainDataGrid.Items[row]);
      cell = (ContentControl)cellContent.Parent;
      var button = new Button {Content="Click me" };
      button.Click += Button_Click;
      oldContent = cell.Content;
      cell.Content = button;
      ExecuteButton.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      cell.Content = oldContent;
      ExecuteButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

While this works, it is a bit of a hack. If the datagrid recreates its content, your button will be lost. This can happen for example, if the user clicks on a column head to sort the grid.

If you REALLY need the dimension of the cell, you can get it with cell.ActualWidth and cell.ActualHeight. But these values might change any time, for example when the user changes the width of the column. Coordinates are not used in WPF. If you need to define the exact place of your control, use it's Margin to position it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the center of the cell:
(shame on you Microsoft, when this solution is ridiculously complex compared to winforms one)

```
    public Point GetCenterPointOfCell(int rowId_0Based, int colId_0Based)
    {
        Point ret = Point.Empty;
        _grid.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            var item = _grid.Items[rowId_0Based];
            int currentRow = _grid.SelectedIndex == -1 ? 0 : _grid.SelectedIndex;
            System.Windows.DependencyObject  dep = _grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(currentRow);
            var dataGridRow = dep as  DataGridRow;
            if (dataGridRow is null)
            {
                string msg = $"Cannot acces row[{currentRow}] of datagrid";
                _log.Error(msg);
                throw new AccessViolationException(msg);
            }
            int visibleRowCount = (int)(_grid.ActualHeight / dataGridRow.ActualHeight * 0.8);
            if (rowId_0Based > _grid.SelectedIndex + visibleRowCount || rowId_0Based < _grid.SelectedIndex)
            {
                object targetScroll;
                if (rowId_0Based + visibleRowCount<_grid.Items.Count)
                {
                    targetScroll = _grid.Items[rowId_0Based + visibleRowCount];
                }
                else
                {
                    targetScroll = item;
                }
                _grid.ScrollIntoView(targetScroll);
                _grid.UpdateLayout();
            }
            var cellContentElement = _grid.Columns[colId_0Based].GetCellContent(item);
            if (cellContentElement == null)
                throw new Exception("cannot get cell content");
            System.Windows.Rect cellBounds = cellContentElement.TransformToAncestor(_grid).TransformBounds(new System.Windows.Rect(0, 0, cellContentElement.ActualWidth, cellContentElement.ActualHeight));
            var centerPoint = new System.Windows.Point((int)(cellBounds.X + cellBounds.Width / 2), (int)(cellBounds.Y + cellBounds.Height / 2));
            System.Windows.Point winPoint = _grid.PointToScreen(centerPoint);
            ret = new Point((int)winPoint.X, (int)winPoint.Y);
        }));
        return ret;
    }
```